# How to create _users database when launching CouchDB in Docker container?

Tags: docker, couchdb

I have created this Dockerfile:

```
FROM couchdb:latest
EXPOSE 5984
COPY local.ini /opt/couchdb/etc/
```

But even though I specified `[admins]` inside of the `local.ini`, I still get this error at launch:

> [error] 2022-11-06T17:55:49.799365Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.15793.0> with exit value:
> {database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,400}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,375}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,404}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,97}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,39}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,198}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,145}]}]}

What do I need to do in order to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM couchdb:latest
EXPOSE 5984
COPY setup.sh setup.sh
RUN sh setup.sh
```

**setup.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh -xe

cat >/opt/couchdb/etc/local.ini <<EOF
[couchdb]
single_node=true

[admins]
dbadmin = $(base32 /dev/random |head -1|cut -c-24)
EOF

nohup bash -c "/docker-entrypoint.sh /opt/couchdb/bin/couchdb &"
sleep 15

curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/_users
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/_replicator
```